# What is the correct way to get wordnet synsets given a unicode word?

Tags: python, utf-8, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to get the wordnet synsents of spanish word 'hipertensión' ('hypertension):

```
wn.synsets(u'hypertension')
[Synset('high_blood_pressure.n.01')]
```

So, the synset exist, but if i use the spanish equivalent:

```
wn.synsets(u'hipertensión',lang='spa')
[]
```

Until here, my basic question.

Some clues: documentation (http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) gives this example:

```
wn.synsets(b'\xe7\x8a\xac'.decode('utf-8'), lang='jpn')
[Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('spy.n.01')]
```

I verified that required type is unicode:

```
type(b'\xe7\x8a\xac'.decode('utf-8'))
<type 'unicode'>
```

what is missing? What follows are some failed experiments

```
wn.synsets( b'hipertensión'.decode('utf-8'), pos=wn.NOUN, lang='spa')
[]

wn.synsets(bytearray('hipertensión').decode('utf-8'), pos=wn.NOUN, lang='spa')
[]

wn.synsets(bytes('hipertensión'), lang='spa')
[]

wn.synsets( u'hipertensión'.decode('utf-8'), pos=wn.NOUN, lang='spa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7  /encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, "hipertensión" does not seem to be a synset on the Spanish side, however "hipertensión_arterial" is.

The following work for me in python2.7:

```
wn.synsets(u'hipertensión_arterial', lang='spa')
wn.synsets(b'hipertensi\xc3\xb3n_arterial'.decode('utf-8'))
```

The way I found "hipertensión_arterial" was via:

```
wn.synsets('hypertension')[0].lemma_names('spa')
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the first thing about WordNet or its API, but judging from your example, you need to encode the unicode string u'hipertensión' first in correct utf-8 *then* decode it:

```
 u'hipertensión'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

and feed that to WordNet:

```
wn.synsets(u'hipertensión'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'), lang="spa")
```

The Japanese example uses b'' because the example string is already utf-8 encoded.

Your u'hipertensión' string is unicode, encoded in a way that is preferred by your python shell/program and/or OS settings - rather unpredictable. So you have to forcibly convert it to utf-8 before decoding it.

Comment: It doesnt work Mr Density 21.5. The code that you propose still gives an empty array: wn.synsets(u'hipertensión'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'), lang="spa") Gives [ ]